# WPF RenderTargetBitmap downscaling text ClearType to GreyScale

Tags: wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF RenderTargetBitmap downscaling TextRenderMode to GreyScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292321/wpf-rendertargetbitmap-downscaling-textrendermode-to-greyscale)

I am writing am Image editing program in WPF, photoshop style.

I have hit a huge hurdle with Text rendering. When I save the canvas to PNG, using RenderTargetBitmap, it reduces the cleartype quality of the text to greyscale and quite honestly looks awful and leave the application useless for the task.

I unfortunately did not expect this sort of limitation when deciding to use WPF.

Does anyone have any work around, or alternative to RenderTargetBitmap to save the canvas to PNG. Or anyway to prevent the "down scaling" of function

I have read on the ms bug report that this is "limitation not a bug", but I hope there is some form of alternative

Many Many thanks

Tommy